# How to access all 8 serial ports on my 8-port serial PCI card

Tags: ubuntu, udev, serial-port, pci

I have installed an 8-port PCI based serial card from [Sunix](http://www.sunix.com.tw/product/ser5066a.html) in my Ubuntu PC.

A probe through `lspci -v` shows the following:

```
03:02.0 Multiport serial controller: SUNIX Co., Ltd. Multiport serial controller
        Subsystem: SUNIX Co., Ltd. Multiport serial controller
        Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 18
        I/O ports at 2100 [size=32]
        I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
        I/O ports at 2120 [size=16]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: serial
```

Also, the following is the output of `ls /dev/ttyS*`:

```
/dev/ttyS0   /dev/ttyS11  /dev/ttyS14  /dev/ttyS17  /dev/ttyS2   /dev/ttyS22  /dev/ttyS25  /dev/ttyS28  /dev/ttyS30  /dev/ttyS5  /dev/ttyS8
/dev/ttyS1   /dev/ttyS12  /dev/ttyS15  /dev/ttyS18  /dev/ttyS20  /dev/ttyS23  /dev/ttyS26  /dev/ttyS29  /dev/ttyS31  /dev/ttyS6  /dev/ttyS9
/dev/ttyS10  /dev/ttyS13  /dev/ttyS16  /dev/ttyS19  /dev/ttyS21  /dev/ttyS24  /dev/ttyS27  /dev/ttyS3   /dev/ttyS4   /dev/ttyS7
```

Now, I was expecting any of the above 8 to be my serial port devices and set to figure out which using the `udevadm` utility as follows:

`udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/ttyS<0-31>)`

And strangely, there are not 8, but just a single port (`/dev/ttyS5`) which can be accessed. Only 2 among the 32 (0-31, yeah, I actually probed each one of them!) were detected with a `SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"` attribute; `udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/ttyS4)` gives the following output:

```
looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.3/tty/ttyS4':
    KERNEL=="ttyS4"
    SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
    DRIVER==""

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.3':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:16.3"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="serial"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x070002"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x1c3d"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{irq}=="17"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-7"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="00ff"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x047e"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1028"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

and `udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/ttyS5)` gives the following output:

```
looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0/0000:03:02.0/tty/ttyS5':
  KERNEL=="ttyS5"
  SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
  DRIVER==""

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0/0000:03:02.0':
  KERNELS=="0000:03:02.0"
  SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
  DRIVERS=="serial"
  ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
  ATTRS{class}=="0x070200"
  ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="32"
  ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"
  ATTRS{device}=="0x1999"
  ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="32"
  ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
  ATTRS{enable}=="1"
  ATTRS{irq}=="18"
  ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-7"
  ATTRS{local_cpus}=="00ff"
  ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
  ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
  ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x0008"
  ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1fd4"
  ATTRS{vendor}=="0x1fd4"

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0':
  KERNELS=="0000:00:1e.0"
  SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
  DRIVERS==""
  ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
  ATTRS{class}=="0x060401"
  ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="32"
  ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="0"
  ATTRS{device}=="0x244e"
  ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="32"
  ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
  ATTRS{enable}=="1"
  ATTRS{irq}=="0"
  ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-7"
  ATTRS{local_cpus}=="00ff"
  ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
  ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
  ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x047e"
  ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1028"
  ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
  KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
  SUBSYSTEMS==""
  DRIVERS==""
```

In addition, I checked the output of `sudo setserial -g /dev/ttyS[0123456789]` too:

```
/dev/ttyS0, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4
/dev/ttyS1, UART: unknown, Port: 0x02f8, IRQ: 3
/dev/ttyS2, UART: unknown, Port: 0x03e8, IRQ: 4
/dev/ttyS3, UART: unknown, Port: 0x02e8, IRQ: 3
/dev/ttyS4, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x4140, IRQ: 17
/dev/ttyS5, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x2100, IRQ: 18
/dev/ttyS6, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS7, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS8, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
/dev/ttyS9, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0
```

The remaining 22 ports/devices returned a similar result `/dev/ttyS31, UART: unknown, Port: 0x0000, IRQ: 0` as well.

The `dmesg` gives me the following prints (I have taken logs related to the PCI device only):

```
[    0.147241] pci 0000:03:02.0: [1fd4:1999] type 00 class 0x070200
[    0.147261] pci 0000:03:02.0: reg 0x10: [io  0x2100-0x211f]
[    0.147269] pci 0000:03:02.0: reg 0x14: [io  0x2000-0x20ff]
[    0.147285] pci 0000:03:02.0: reg 0x1c: [io  0x2120-0x212f]
[    0.147326] pci 0000:03:02.0: PME# supported from D3hot
[    0.644260] 0000:03:02.0: ttyS5 at I/O 0x2100 (irq = 18, base_baud = 921600) is a 16550A
```

Another clue I got (from an answer below) is that `ttyS5` is the only one listed under the PCI device `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.3` in my PC (Please note that this particular PCI card was working fine when it was installed in a Windows 7 based PC). The following is the output of `find /sys/devices/ -type d -name ttyS*`:

```
/sys/devices/pnp0/00:04/tty/ttyS0
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.3/tty/ttyS4
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1e.0/0000:03:02.0/tty/ttyS5
/sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS1
/sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS2
/sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS3
/sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS6
/sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS7
/sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS8
/sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS9
/sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS10
/sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS11
/sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS12
/sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS13
/sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS14
/sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS15
/sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS16
/sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS17
/sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS18
/sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS19
/sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS20
/sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS21
/sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS22
/sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS23
/sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS24
/sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS25
/sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS26
/sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS27
/sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS28
/sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS29
/sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS30
/sys/devices/platform/serial8250/tty/ttyS31
```

I would like to understand and know why only my port labelled `1` on my Sunix is accessible and how/where can I gain access to my remaining 7 ports?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some in-depth research, I got a custom driver from here:

www.sunix.com/en/download.php?pid=970&file=driver&file_link=download/driver/2016/20160706173626_snx_V2.0.4.2.tar.gz

For some reason (that I'm unaware of), the kernel doesn't seem to recognize the other serial ports. So, I got it fixed by doing the following:

Download the driver from the link above. "ncurses.h" is a dependency for the above driver. Install it using `apt` as:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```

Change to root directory (to install the driver), create a new directory `temp` and make `temp` your working directory:

```
cd /
sudo mkdir temp
cd /temp
```

Copy the `tar` file and extract the contents to `/temp`:

```
sudo cp ~/Downloads/20160706173626_snx_V2.0.4.2.tar.gz /temp/snx_V2.0.4.2.tar.gz
sudo tar xvf snx_V2.0.4.2.tar.gz
```

Install the driver using the following steps:

```
sudo make clean
sudo make install
sudo modprobe snx
```

Run `lsmod | grep snx` to verify. New device files should be created with a prefix as `ttySNX` (instead of `ttyS`). The same can be checked using `ls /dev/ttySNX*`, which should be giving the following output:

```
/dev/ttySNX0  /dev/ttySNX1  /dev/ttySNX2  /dev/ttySNX3  /dev/ttySNX4  /dev/ttySNX5  /dev/ttySNX6  /dev/ttySNX7
```

So, the bottomline is : Linux may not be able to do magic (which it does more often than not) and make every device work in a plug and play manner, it may need drivers to some specific devices.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in the kernel driver as it shouldn't have created this many devices. You should check the kernel debug messages to see if anything went wrong during the driver init.

Comment: Would `dmesg` prints be of any help?

Comment: Yes, look for the serial port driver messages.

Comment: I just updated my post with the same.

Comment: Does `dmesg` say anything about all the next ttys?

Comment: Nope. All it says is `[    0.602427] 00:04: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    0.623717] 0000:00:16.3: ttyS4 at I/O 0x4140 (irq = 17, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    0.644260] 0000:03:02.0: ttyS5 at I/O 0x2100 (irq = 18, base_baud = 921600) is a 16550A`